# Android studio socks proxy issue

Tags: android-studio, tor

Due to the political prohibitions (country related), unfortunately i am unable to connect to google servers normally, however i have to be able to develop android applications for educational purposes. So i decided to use socks proxy and redirect my traffic through tor so i can be able to get SDK and other API tools and get android studio running. Previously i did this and worked, but now after a fresh ubuntu install and getting the most recent android studio version and following the official instructions, i can't manage to get android studio connect to tor. I tried using the exact host name and port number with other applications and it worked. but i can't seem to find any realted topic to solve my own problem.

```
Host name: localhost
Port: 9150
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently setting the proxy in android studio's settings was not enough.

Besides the starting script must be run like this:

```
$ torsocks -P 9150 /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? where should I run that?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani You would basically start tor browser (or tor client if you like) and then execute the command mentioned on this answer, (tor browser uses 9150 and tor client uses 9050 by default). Also torsocks is provided with most Linux distributions.